# MKMapView in UICollectionViewCell, didSelectItemAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView where a few of the cells contains a MKMapView. Tapping in these cells on the mapView does not trigger didSelectItemAtIndexPath for the UICollectionView, in all other cells it works fine.

I understand that this probably is since MKMapView intercepts the taps, and for that reason I have turned of all the interaction that is available for the mapview.

```
cell.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But even if the user interaction is disabled, the didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not called when the mapView is shown and tapped on in the cell.

How can you entirely disabled gestureRecognizers on the mapView to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting a bit more it turned out that it works when the user interaction is disabled in code (as in the question), but not from the settings in interface builder.

I have verified that this is the issue in my case, the "User Interaction Enabled" setting in IB for the MapView do not have effect in this case. Disabling the user interaction programmatically in collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) works fine however.